# TCP/UDP And NAT

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, nat

My friend told me that TCP doesn't need port forward.
What exactly he said is if the server is port forwarded the client can request something and the server will respond without port forward.
And I agreed with that even though I'm not sure it is true.

Later he said it is the same with UDP which I do not believe.

MAINLY THE QUESTION IS
If a client requests something on a server with TCP, does it need to be port forwarded to receive the response?
Also is it the same for UDP?

Comment: Port forwarding is something that happens between a router and a machine when NAT is employed. If your router doesn't know which machine to forward requests to on the network when it receives a request, what you you expect to happen?

Comment: This is more a question about IP/NAT as TCP and UDP are just part of the transport layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request from the client is a SYN for connect call then only a SYN-ACK response will be allowed through NAT. If the NAT supports simultaneous open connection then a SYN response from server will also be allowed through NAT. After the connection is established then client and server can communicate freely without any restriction. Port forwarding is not needed.

For UDP after a packet from client to server is sent then anything from server can be received through exact same public port of the NAT from which the first packet was sent. No port forwarding needed.